# add file property (like jQuery's .data()) to a GDrive file - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, file-properties

I was wondering if there's a way to append to a GDrive file some sort of information using Google App Script. For example, I'm currently working on some google Spreadsheets with GAS, and I really need to append to these spreadsheet some useful informations, like "already seen" or "already processed".

I was looking for something like `jQuery's .data()`, but till now I haven't found anything.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
ss.data("processed", "true").data("seen", "false")  //--- something like this
```

Does anyone know if it is possible? Any workaround or trick to accomplish that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found (maybe in the future there will be the possibility to add data to a GDrive file), using GAS, is using the file description to get/set additional info..

```
// Gets the first document's description.
// Note: This can also be used on a folder
var doc = DocsList.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.DOCUMENT)[0];
Logger.log(doc.getDescription());

// This example sets the first document's description
// Note: This can also be used on a folder
var doc = DocsList.getFilesByType(DocsList.FileType.DOCUMENT)[0];
doc.setDescription('My First Doc');
Logger.log(doc.getDescription()); // logs 'My First Doc'
```

Documentation [**HERE**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#getDescription())

I use the description field to store all my info, separated by a pipe. When I need to get a particular file info, I parse the description string looking for what I need.. basically works like a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what might interest you is [Drives custom file properties.](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/properties) You can find more on the methods [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties#resource). I'm pretty new to programming, and I've never used this particular feature, but I believe it will allow you to specify custom properties for Drive files.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. I believe the method I've outlined above is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it's not possible as you want. There is only one way to set your custom properties using [Google Drive Web API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/insert) for now.